# Necesito centrar la mirila jquery css

Tags: html, css

tengo una mirilla para un juego hecho con jquery css y html, el cursor esta en la parte de arriba a la izquierda en realiad no en el centro de la mira, alguna sugerencia?
Gracias de antemano
el css es así

cursor: url("img/reticle.png"), auto;

Comment: Como entenderás sin nada de soporte a la pregunta es prácticamente imposible poder ayudarte. Agrega código o parte de lo que lleves echo para poder echarte un cable

Comment: Espero que te sirviera mi respuesta adicionalmente intenta que el área de efecto para tu eventos tenga un padding para no perder todos los puntos de disparo, si es de que eso se tratase tu juego, mucho éxito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno esto es simple cursor puede agregar cuando de x y cuanto de y al final te agrego un ejemplo simple y funcional en tu caso y en este como de la imagen seria la mitad del tamaño de la misma tanto en x como en y

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  body {
    background-color: #000000;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    cursor:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozdqm.png) 12 12, auto;
  }
  div {
    padding: 40px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="area"></div>
 
<script>
$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
  $( "#area" ).text( "X: " + event.pageX + ", Y: " + event.pageY );
});
</script>
 
 
 
</body>
</html>
```